# Read Firebase authentication records with R

Tags: r, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using R, I am trying to read the Firebase authentication records created by users for our project, `projectID`. To be clear, I do not wish to read, nor can I read, the user pswd, just the Firebase authentication ID, known as the User UID.

Firebase creates a unique UID when a user record is created. This in turn populates a collection, call it `collectionID`, where the key to `collectionID` is the Firebase authentication `User UID`. Other information about the user's use of our application is stored within this collection.

I can read the collectionID using the Firestore library created by Luis Rodriguez  - [github("luizmirodriguez/FireStore")](https://github.com/luizmirodriguez/FireStore/) - as follows:

```js
fireStore.download(projectID,collectionID,auth$credentials$access_token).
```

I cannot download the authentication records shown in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) with R today. Does anyone know how to do this?

It may be as simple as knowing the name of the collection (`authentication`, `authentication/users`, `authentication/users_uid` all produce errors).

Any help appreciated